# How to dismiss keyboard in Android SearchView?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-3.0-honeycomb, searchview

I have a searchView in the ActionBar. I want to dismiss the keyboard when the user is done with input. I have the following queryTextListener on the searchView

```
final SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() { 
    @Override 
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) { 
        // Do something 
        return true; 
    } 

    @Override 
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

        showProgress();
        // Do stuff, make async call

        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

        return true; 
    } 
};
```

Based on similar questions, the following code should dismiss the keyboard, but it doesn't work in this case:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

I've also tried:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchView.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Neither one works. I'm not sure if this is a Honeycomb specific problem or if it's related to the searchView in the ActionBar, or both. Has anyone gotten this working or know why it does not work?

Answer (score 71):

I was trying to do something similar. I needed to launch the `SearchActivity` from another `Activity` and have the search term appear on the opened search field when it loaded. I tried all the approaches above but finally (similar to [Ridcully's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9515207/1276636)) I set a variable to `SearchView` in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and then in `onQueryTextSubmit()` called `clearFocus()` on the `SearchView` when the user submitted a new search:

```
private SearchView searchView;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search)
            .getActionView(); // set the reference to the searchView
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this); 
    searchMenuItem = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search); 
    searchMenuItem.expandActionView(); // expand the search action item automatically
    searchView.setQuery("<put your search term here>", false); // fill in the search term by default
    searchView.clearFocus(); // close the keyboard on load
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    performNewSearch(query);
    searchView.clearFocus();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: where is ``query`` defined in ``onCreateOptionsMenu``?

Comment: ..that is the query string that is defined elsewhere. i'll edit it out . That line is also not needed, it is only if you want to pre-fill the query and the second argument (false) stops it from running the query.

Comment: Thank you very much! searchView.clearFocus() is the part I missing till now

Comment: Don't use `searchView.clearFocus() ` because some next view will be focused with animation (I don't think you want to do it)

Comment: you should return false

Answer (score 40):

Simple, straight to the point and clean:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
      // your search methods
      searchView.clearFocus();
      return true;
  }
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer as per the documentation,

Returns boolean: true if the query has been handled by the listener, false to let the SearchView perform the default action. 

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener.html#onQueryTextSubmit(java.lang.String)

Comment: Don't use `searchView.clearFocus() ` because some next view will be focused with animation (I don't think you want to do it)

Comment: you should return false

Answer (score 28):

just return false on onQueryTextSubmit just like below

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
     return false;
}
```

Comment: @lostintranslation because it's a normal UI behavior

Answer (score 12):

For me, none of the above was working on the first submit. It was hiding and then immediately re-showing the keyboard. I had to post the `clearFocus()` on the view's handler to make it happen after it was done with everything else.

```
mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                if (!"".equals(query)) {
                    mSearchView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mSearchView.clearFocus();
                        }
                    });
                }
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 11):

Somehow it works if you call

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchView.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

and then

```
otherWidget.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 7):

For me, the following works:

In my activity I have a member variable

```
private SearchView mSearchView;
```

In `onCreateOptionsMenu()` I set that variable like so:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.library, menu);
    mSearchView = (SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.miSearch).getActionView();
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return true;
}
```

In the `QueryTextListener` at last, I do this:

```
mSearchView.setQuery("", false);
mSearchView.setIconified(true);
```

I had a look at the source code of SearchView, and if you do not reset the query text to an empty string, the SearchView just does that, and does not remove the keyboard neither. Actually, drilling down deep enough in the source code, it comes to the same, yuku suggested, but still I like my solution better, as I do not have to mess around with those low level stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I added the better solution on top, but also kept the old answer as a reference.

```
 @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                  searchView.clearFocus();
            return false;
        }
```

Original Answer: I programmed using a setOnQueryTextListener. When the searchview is hidden the keyboard goes away and then when it is visible again the keyboard does not pop back up.

```
    //set query change listener
     searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            /**
             * hides and then unhides search tab to make sure keyboard disappears when query is submitted
             */
                  searchView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                  searchView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return false;
        }

     });
```

Comment: Why are you using magic numbers, rather than the constants themselves?  Also, this is just a hacky answer.

Answer (score 2):

if someone is looking how to collpase searchView/keyboard, use below code

```
     /*
        setup close button listener
     */
    searchView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.search_close_btn).setOnClickListener {
        adapter.filter(null)//reset default list
        searchView.onActionViewCollapsed() //collapse SearchView/Keyboard
        true
    }

    /*
        setup text change listener
     */
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object:SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {

            adapter.filter(if(query.isNullOrEmpty()) "" else query)

            searchView.onActionViewCollapsed() //collapse SearchView/Keyboard
            return true
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            adapter.filter(if(newText.isNullOrEmpty()) "" else newText)
            return true
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

In a tablet app I'm working on with a dual pane activity, I've wrote only

`f.getView().requestFocus(); // f is the target fragment for the search`

and that was enough to dismiss the soft keyboard after a search. No need to use InputMethodManager

Answer (score 1):

I used ActionBarSherlock 4.3 and I have a ProgressDialog. When I dismiss it in postExecute method, Searchview gain focus. To fix that:

```
//Handle intent and hide soft keyboard
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
        searchView.setQuery("", false);
        searchView.setIconified(true);
        searchView.clearFocus();
    }

    /*When dismiss ProgressDialog, searchview gain focus again and shows the keyboard. I  call clearFocus() to avoid it.*/

    AsyncTask.onPostExecute(){
      if(pd!=null)
        pd.dismiss();
      if(searchView!=null)
        searchView.clearFocus();
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it.

```
if (isKeybordShowing(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this.getCurrentFocus())) {
    onBackPressed();
}

public boolean isKeybordShowing(Context context, View view) {
    try {
        InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        keyboard.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        return keyboard.isActive();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("keyboardHide", "cannot hide keyboard", ex);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and the simple way to hide or show the soft keyboard if you are kotlin developer create a simple **Kotlin extension function** and add this following code

**For kotlin developer's**

```
fun View.hideSoftKeyboard() {
val context = context ?: return // get the context
val imm = ContextCompat.getSystemService(context, InputMethodManager::class.java)
imm?.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.windowToken, 0) // you can get the current windowtoken from view where you call this function
```

}

For Java Developer (java has a no extension function) because it is purely oop's language

```
public class Utils {

public static void hideSoftKeyboard(View view) {
    Context context = view.getContext();
    if (context == null) {
        return;
    }

    InputMethodManager imm = ContextCompat.getSystemService(context, InputMethodManager.class);
    if (imm != null) {
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Two solutions that worked for me, the first one using the SearchView instance:

```
private void hideKeyboard(){
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchView.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Second solution:

```
private void hideKeyboard(){
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Below Code is working for me to hide keyboard in Searchview

```
MenuItem searchItem = baseMenu.findItem(R.id.menuSearch);

edtSearch= (EditText) searchItem.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);

MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                            edtSearch.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
                                }
                            });
                            return true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you try this? When you touch the X button, you trigger a focus on the searchview no matter what.

```
ImageView closeButton = (ImageView)searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_close_btn);
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
                et.setText("");`enter code here`
                searchView.setQuery("", false);
                searchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
                menuSearch.collapseActionView();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
fun View.hideKeyboard() {
    val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        searchView.clearFocus();
    }
```

I tried all the answers above but none worked, clearing focus onResume worked for me