# Can't disable Action Bar Sherlock's Search View from opening soft input keyboard

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, searchview

I'm using the Action Bar Sherlock SearchView in my UI. I have been trying to disable the opening of the soft input keyboard but it's not working. So far I have tried these methods.

1. I used the input manager to disable the showing of the soft input keyboard.

   ```
   View target = this.getView().findFocus();
   if(target!=null)
   {
       InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSherlockActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
       imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(target.getWindowToken(), 0);
   }
   ```
2. I set `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` in the manifest's activity tag like so.

   ```
   <activity
           android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
           android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
           android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:label="@string/app_name"
           >
   ```

Nevertheless the keyboard is still popping up.

My SearchView implementation

```
 <com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/customView"
    android:id="@+id/searchView" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>

    /* Code used to hide focus */
    searchView =(SearchView)view.findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    searchView.setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645799/android-how-to-unfocus-a-searchview-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply just used `searchView.clearFocus()` and that stopped the keyboard from popping up.

Answer (score 0):

To disable any view (e.g. SearchView):

either set its **input-type to "none"** in XML or **view.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)** from the Activity