# How hide keyboard after voice input in SearchView

Tags: java, android

I have a SearchView in the application and when I use the voice search, a key appears. How to remove the appearance of the keyboard?
I tried to remove focus after onQueryTextChanged but after that it's impossible to use text input. Any ideas?

Comment: Try looking at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409288/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-in-android-searchview

Comment: Yes, i have similar problem. But i need to distinguish keyboard input and voice input. and only when I use voice search I need to hide the keyboard in onQueryTextChanged(), but in other cases I do not need.